# How do we prove that $f^{-1}(B)$ is a subgroup of $G$ if $f$ is a homomorphism between $G$ and $H$ and $B$ is a subgroup of $H$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $f:G\to H$ be a homomorphism of groups. If $B\leq H$, show that $f^{-1}(B) \leq G$.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Yadda yadda. Please show some effort /working so that we can try to help you. What have you tried?

Comment: Sorry about that. Here's my work:

Comment: What is blocking you exactly ? Are you familiar with all these notions (i.e. do you understand them and know their definition)  ?

Comment: Since B is a subgroup of H, then $e\in B$ implies that $e\in f^{-1}(B)$. Moreover, $h\in H$ implies that $h^{-1}\in H$ and so $f^{-1}(g^{-1})=f^{-1}(g)^{-1}\in f^{-1}(B)$. I'm finding trouble on the associativity part and closure part.

Comment: I don't know if I'm doing it right

Comment: About the associativity, remember that all the elements of $f^{-1}(B)$ can be considered as elements of $G$, and the composition law is the same in $f^{-1}(B)$ and in $G$.

Comment: Please put your efforts into the *question*. A comment isn't a good place for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your comment, I found some misconception.

(1) $f^{-1}(B)$ denote the pre-image of $B$. Alternatively, we write $$f^{-1}(B)=\{g\in G:f(g)\in B\}$$
Since $f$ is not necessarily a bijection, it may not have an inverse. So it is not correct to write $f^{-1}(g^{-1})=f^{-1}(g)^{-1}$ for $g\in G$.

(2) There is a bit of gap for you to straight away conclude that $e\in B$ implies that $e\in f^{-1}(B)$. To explain it in details, you have to argue that since $B$ is a subgroup of $H$, hence $e_H\in B$. Since $f$ is a homomorphism, $f(e_G)=e_H$. Hence from $f(e_G)=e_H\in B$, we conclude that $e_G\in f^{-1}(B)$.

(3) As pointed out by Chris Custer, you can use the subgroup criterion to prove that $f^{-1}(B)$ is a subgroup of $G$. But you also have to show that this set is nonempty and this is done in (2).

Let $x,y\in f^{-1}(B)$. By definition, we have $f(x),f(y)\in B$. Since $B$ is a subgroup of $H$, we have $f(x)f(y)^{-1}\in B$. Since $f$ is a homomorphism, $f(x)f(y)^{-1}=f(xy^{-1})$. So from $f(xy^{-1})\in B$, this implies that $xy^{-1}\in f^{-1}(B)$ and we use subgroup criterion to conclude that $f^{-1}(B)$ is a subgroup of $G$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:  You can use the subgroup criterion:  $H\subset G$ is a subgroup if and only if $ab^{-1}\in H\,,\forall a,b\in H$.